# Switched capacitor IC

Tags: resistors, switching

I wanted to make a switched capacitance resistance, like shown in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor#The_switched_capacitor_resistor. Is it possible to make such circuits on breadboards? If possible is there any IC with we can directly make such circuits?
For what range of resistance values will I get a reliable results? Is there a restriction on what values of capacitance I use.

Thanx..:)

Comment: Looks too broad to me. What is your application?

Comment: Well I am making a filter for which the center frequency can be tuned by changing resistance values. I wanted to automate this circuit by using a micro controller, it can be done using digital potentiometers but i  live in India it is really hard to get them in short time. There switched capacitor filters that are available in ICs but it is not possible to make a filter of my specification with these ICs. So I had to make my own filter circuit. But now i am facing problems with automating it. I have to automate the changing of resistance.

Comment: I wanted resistance in the the range of 500k to 10M ohms. Is it too broad range to ask for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make switched capacitors on a breadboard, although be aware of parasitics.  What do you mean directly make circuits?  Buy some switches and a cap and connect it to an oscillator.  If you mean an switched-cap filter, the MF10 is well known and available from multiple sources.  Depending on the cap and oscillator you use you could easily get in the 10s of kohm.  The main restriction on the size of capacitor is that it needs to be large enough that it is much larger than the stray capacitance on your breadboard.

Comment: how high should the capacitance be?

Comment: By switches you mean CD4066, But the problem with this IC is that it has a high ON resistance, Or mean you meant any specific resistance?

Comment: As long as your desired switched capacitance is large relative to the switch on resistance you should be ok.  As far as how high should the capacitance be?  Well, it is C = 1/(f*R) right?